# How to implement a class (function) upon pressing a key?

Tags: python, keyboard

I have a function in my code:

```
X = []
Y = [1,2,3,4]
class DATA():
    def __init__(self):
        X.append(Y)
DATA()
print (X)
```

When I run my code, I want this class (named `DATA`) to be implemented **only when I press the *<kbd>Enter</kbd> key*.**  Any idea how I can do it? (A simple example is appreciated!).

Comment: What do you mean by `I want this class (named DATA) to be implemented only when I press Enter key`? You want the entire class of DATA to not exist until enter is pressed, or you don't want `DATA(); print(x);` to run until enter is pressed?

Comment: You mean you don't want the class definition itself executed until you press enter, or you don't want an instance of created until you press enter? Either way, everything in Python is just normal runtime code, so just add `input('Press Enter to continue')` or whatever before the relevant code, and it won't run until the user presses Enter.

Comment: As a side note, what exactly is the point of this class? Its instances don't actually do anything except for their constructor's side effect, so… why isn't it just a function?

Comment: Do you mean a class ***or*** a function (or perhaps a class method)? They're not interchangeable (although all are callable).

Comment: I mean the class. If I call the class the function is automatically implemented. When I run the code, I want this class to be implemented after pressing ENTER key. To be more specific, it is only a part of my code. When I run the code I want everything in my code to  run except this class that should be implemented after I press ENTER key.

Comment: @Leo So you only want `class DATA` to run after you hit enter? That's almost definitely not what you should be doing. I think the abarnert is right. You should just be using a plain function here. There doesn't seem to be any point to the DATA class.

Comment: In this example, get rid of the `class` and just replace it with `def some_function(): X.append(Y)`. That's still not perfect, but it makes sense now at least.

Comment: If I do what you said (removing the class and using only a function as you said) so how could I get what I want? Again: I want the whole code to run except this function and I want this function to be implemented only when I press a key (like ENTER). It is exactly what I am looking for. I guess it would be really helpful if someone could provide a simple example.

Comment: @Leo Sec, my breaks over now. Make sure to tag people so they get notified that you're mentioning them. I'll answer this on my next break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was hard to answer for a couple reasons:

- You keep using the word "implement", but I'm pretty sure you mean "call" instead. I'm going to assume that here, since conditionally implementing something is rarely needed.
- Your use of the class here is confusing. It isn't actually needed in this case, so it's just complicating things. I'm going to reduce it down to just:

  ```
  def DATA():
      X.append(Y)
  ```

  Since that does the same thing as your existing code.

---

To ask for user input, use `input`. `input` waits *until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>*, then returns the typed text. You can use it here to wait for <kbd>Enter</kbd> to be pressed:

```
x = []
y = [1,2,3,4]

def data():
    x.append(y)

print("x before Enter is pressed:")
print(x)

input("Type Enter to continue...")
data() #Call DATA similar to your original code

print("x after Enter is pressed:")
print(x)
```

---

A couple extra notes:

- Function and variables names should be in lower case. Uppercase is reserved for class names, and even in those cases, only the first letter is uppercase.
- Ideally, you shouldn't be mutating global variables like `x` and `y`. They should be passed into the function, then  the result should be returned.